# Log-likelihood function reference

Tags: log-likelihood

I am learning a code that uses CUSUM to detect changes. The code uses log-likelihood function:

logp = stepsize*basesd/variance * (data[k] - mean - stepsize*basesd/2.) (instantaneous log-likelihood for current sample assuming local baseline has jumped in the positive direction)

logn = -stepsize*basesd/variance * (data[k] - mean + stepsize*basesd/2.) (instantaneous log-likelihood for current sample assuming local baseline has jumped in the negative direction)

May I know from where i can learn this function whose formula is implemented that way or in a similar manner?

Comment: What is $CUSUM$?

Comment: CUSUM is used accumulate small changes in local baseline (I'm dealing with electrical signal) due to random noise and not due to persistent change